# How to get to NSDates of the midnights bracketing any date?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

Given any NSDate, how would I get the dates for the last midnight and the next midnight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly complex, but doable:

```
NSDate *date = ...;
NSUInteger componentFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:componentFlags fromDate:date];
NSDateComponents *midnightComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[midnightComponents setDay:[parts day]];
[midnightComponents setMonth:[parts month]];
[midnightComponents setYear:[parts year]];
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *midnight = [cal dateFromComponents:midnightComponents];

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:1];
NSDate *nextMidnight = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate: midnight options:0];
```

I think Apple's design overcomplicated things a bit, compared to, say, .NET or even Java, but it is manageable.

Comment: The oneDay here will break if there is a time change (daylight savings time, etc).  You should reuse midnightComponents and add one day to it to create the second date.  Other than that though, this is the right approach.  +1

Comment: Oh, and also:  use currentCalendar (the second time) instead of the Gregorian calendar.  These apps are used world wide!  :)

Comment: @lnafziger Thanks! It turns out that the problem is even more complex than I thought :)

Comment: Yeah, I've done too much with these routines, lol.  They can handle just about anything though.  IF people can figure out how.